# How to make text editor in Visual Studio looks like this?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I've found this project [Structured Editor](http://structurededitor.codeplex.com) that presents an experimental structured code editor prototype.

I love this idea and want this in Visual Studio, what options I have ?

[image: Structured Editor]

Comment: The link the screenshot is broken for me - you also might want to consider embedding it as an image in your post rather than as a link.

Comment: There's no anything similar for Visual Studio. The only available option is to make your own plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stuff is possible to do with Visual Studio extensions. As far as I know there is no Visual Studio extension that does exactly what you want, but [Indent Guides](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30) is similar.

The [source code for Indent Guides is available](http://indentguide.codeplex.com/) so if you're so inclined, you could modify that to show gradients instead of lines.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still on 2008.

Comment: Ah, then it's probably still possible to do, but *a lot* more work. If you're willing to put in the effort and code it your self, look into the DXCore framework from DevExpress. That might make things easier. Out of curiosity, what's stopping you from upgrading to VS2010?

Comment: Some plugins exist only for vs2008, like [rockscroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx) or [metalscroll](http://code.google.com/p/metalscroll/), there is Productivity Power Tools but I prefer metalscroll, and for me VS2010 little slower.